# How to Configure A New Monitor As the Only Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, amd-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I'm not familiar with X. When I installed the OS, I was temporarily using an old monitor, with an HDMI to VGA adapter. Then, I bought a new monitor and found that Ubuntu gave me a black screen on the new monitor. Later, I found that before I login, it can only display on the old monitor and after logging in, it can display normally on my new monitor. What I have to do now is to plug in the old monitor, log in, and unplug the old monitor, switch to the new one (with a single HDMI port on the graphics card).

What I suspect is that Ubuntu "remembers" the old monitor and treats it as the primary monitor, so it displays login screen only on the old one.

I'm wondering is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Does the new display show the boot splash and go black at login? Or is it off the entire time the system is booting?

Comment: @matigo It shows UEFI screen during booting, and goes black at login.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the easiest fix is to reset `xrandr`. Here's how:

**If you are booting with the new display connected:**

0. When your system finishes booting and goes to a black screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
   <sup>**Note:** You should be able to use any of the <kbd>F#</kbd> keys for this, but <kbd>F1</kbd> is a fine place to start.</sup>
1. Log into the system via the console
2. Move on to the "Reset `xrandr`" section of this answer

**If you are booting with the previous display connected:**

0. Boot normally
1. Sign in normally
2. Open Terminal

**Reset `xrandr`:**

0. Reset `xrandr`:

   ```
   xrandr -s 0
   ```
1. There is no further step ... hopefully.

**What this does:**

From [the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xrandr.1.html) regarding the `-s` option:

```
-s, --size size-index or --size widthxheight
    This sets the screen size, either matching by size or using the index into the list
    of available sizes.
```

So `-s 0` will reset the connected display to use the first available size identified via the HDMI handshake. If you would like to see a full list of display resolutions available, you can do so like this:

```
xrandr -d :0
```

Which will give you something like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   ...
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If your graphics adapter has just a single HDMI output, then you will likely see information just for `HDMI-1`.

Comment: With the new display connected, I ran the `xrandr -s 0` command and reboot the computer. It still gives a black screen during login. I called out console by CTRL+ALT+F5, and `xrandr -s 0` gives something like `Can't open screen`. The problem persists.

Comment: What do you see when you type `xrandr -q` after getting the `Can't open screen` message?

Comment: `xrandr -q` also gives `Can' open display`, the same happens to a single command `xrandr`

Comment: This is most irregular. As a final measure, let's name the display and set a resolution: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080`. Generally when this sort of issue is persistent, it's because the HDMI device is not sending any signal back to the video card, but it would be very odd for a display to *not* do this. And, as you can get the new display to work when connecting it after the fact, it must be sending *some* configuration data back. Are you using an XFCE desktop or the default Gnome? 

Comment: When I'm using the new monitor after login, `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080` works well (I assume no change meaning it works well since I'm using a resolution at 1920x1080). When I reboot the machine, call out `tty5` before login, and input that command, `Can't open display` happens again. Maybe there's no X session at all when using `tty5`?

Comment: Or your graphical console is not `tty5` but `tty7` ⇢ [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F7] 

Comment: It's quite interesting... CTRL+ALT+F1 gives a black screen. I type my username and password blindly and then it goes to the normal desktop. I assume it's the normal login screen. CTRL+ALT+F2 to CTRL+ALT+F6 give `tty2` to `tty6`, and in each session, `xrandr` gives `Can't open display`. CTRL+ALT+F7 gives a line `/dev/sda2: clean, xxx/xxxx files, xxx/xxxx blocks`